# ANDROID STUDIO: Problema al pasar el contexto como parámetro a una función

Tags: java, android, android-studio, android-context, context

Tengo un problema al pasar como parámetro el contexto, a una función de otra clase java desde una activity. Y es que en la clase en la que necesito el contexto, no puedo utilizar la función **getPackageName()**.

```
public static void rellenarCartas(List<ImageView> figurasC1, List<ImageView> figurasC2, List<ArrayList> planoJuego, ArrayList<String> cartas, Context context){
        Random random = new Random();
        //RELLENAR CARTA 1
        int card = random.nextInt(planoJuego.size());
        for (int i = 0; i < figurasC1.size(); i++){
            int carta = (int) planoJuego.get(card).get(i);
            int id = context.getResources().getIdentifier(cartas.get(carta), "drawable", getPackageName());
            figurasC1.get(i).setImageResource(id);
        }
        planoJuego.remove(card);

        //RELLENAR CARTA 2
        int card2 = random.nextInt(planoJuego.size());
        for (int i = 0; i < figurasC2.size(); i++){
            int carta2 = (int) planoJuego.get(card2).get(i);
            int id = context.getResources().getIdentifier(cartas.get(carta2), "drawable", getPackageName());
            figurasC2.get(i).setImageResource(id);
        }
        planoJuego.remove(card2);
    }
```

Lo que necesito es obtener los ids:
**int id = context.getResources().getIdentifier(cartas.get(carta2), "drawable", getPackageName());**
Pero me arroja el fallo de que no reconoce **getPackageName()**.

```
error: cannot find symbol
            int id = context.getResources().getIdentifier(cartas.get(carta), "drawable", getPackageName());
                                                                                         ^
  symbol:   method getPackageName()
  location: class crearCartas
```

Esto funciona perfectamente si tengo el código en la propia actividad y omito el contexto al obtener las id's.

Esta función, rellenarCartas(), la llamo desde una activity, y le paso *this* como parámetro para el contexto:

```
//DESDE LA ACTIVITY
for (int i = 0; i <= orden; i++){
            String c1 = "figura" + (i+1) + "_carta1";
            String c2 = "figura" + (i+1) + "_carta2";
            int id1 = getResources().getIdentifier(c1, "id", getPackageName());
            int id2 = getResources().getIdentifier(c2, "id", getPackageName());
            ImageView imgViewC1 = (ImageView) findViewById(id1);
            ImageView imgViewC2 = (ImageView) findViewById(id2);
            figurasC1.add(imgViewC1);
            figurasC2.add(imgViewC2);
        }

crearCartas.rellenarCartas(figurasC1,figurasC2,planoJuego, cartas, this);
```

También he probado de esta manera pero no lo he conseguido:

```
//DESDE LA ACTIVITY
crearCartas creCar = new crearCartas(this);
creCar.rellenarCartas(figurasC1, figurasC2, planoJuego, cartas);
```

```
public class crearCartas  {
    private Context context;
    public crearCartas(Context context){
        this.context = context;
    }
public static void rellenarCartas(List<ImageView> figurasC1, List<ImageView> figurasC2, List<ArrayList> planoJuego, ArrayList<String> cartas){
        Random random = new Random();
        //RELLENAR CARTA 1
        int card = random.nextInt(planoJuego.size());
        for (int i = 0; i < figurasC1.size(); i++){
            int carta = (int) planoJuego.get(card).get(i);
            int id = context.getResources().getIdentifier(cartas.get(carta), "drawable", getPackageName());
            figurasC1.get(i).setImageResource(id);
        }
        planoJuego.remove(card);

        //RELLENAR CARTA 2
        int card2 = random.nextInt(planoJuego.size());
        for (int i = 0; i < figurasC2.size(); i++){
            int carta2 = (int) planoJuego.get(card2).get(i);
            int id = context.getResources().getIdentifier(cartas.get(carta2), "drawable", getPackageName());
            figurasC2.get(i).setImageResource(id);
        }
        planoJuego.remove(card2);
    }
```

Gracias de antemano. Saludos.

Comment: Se aporta una solución posible en el siguiente enlace: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16369814/how-to-access-the-drawable-resources-by-name-in-android

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Para evitar el error:

> error: cannot find symbol getPackageName()

Puedes usar la misma variable `context` para llamar el método `getPackageName()` , ya que el método es parte de la clase [Context](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Context):

```
int id = context.getResources().getIdentifier(cartas.get(carta2), "drawable", context.getPackageName());
```

Comment: Como aporte, puede que no le evidente que: `Activity` desciende de `Context` por lo que la función `getPackageName` es heredada a `Activity`. Cómo cualquier otra función definida en la misma clase, se puede llamar tan solo con su nombre y paréntesis. Entonces parece que `getPackageName` es una función que se puede llamar desde cualquier parte.

Comment: Muchas gracias a ambos, Jorgesys y @Mateo. Y disculpad no haber contestado con anterioridad. Saludos